# RTL8812AU driver listed in lsmod, but not working

Tags: networking, drivers, apt, usb, kernel

I have a TP-Link Archer T2U Plus USB WiFi adapter that has the Realtek RTL88**21**AU chipset. The driver isn't preinstalled on Ubuntu **20.04.3** (kernel **5.11.0-27-generic**, if it is preinstalled on 21.10 or 20.04.4, please let me know and I will upgrade) so I had to manually install the driver. I found one in the universe (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/rtl8812au-dkms) that's made for the RTL88**12**AU, but it also works for RTL88**21**AU, because there is RTL88**21**AU written in the `/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c` file.

I installed it with `sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms`, however, the driver doesn't work, because TP-Link Archer T2U Plus's ID isn't listed in the `/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c` file. So I downloaded the source code of the driver (using `apt download rtl8812au-dkms`), unzipped the .deb file, got the ID from the `lsusb` command (it's **2357:0120**) and added a line

```
{USB_DEVICE(0x2357, 0x0120), .driver_info = RTL8821}, /* TP Link - T2U Plus */
```

under `#ifdef CONFIG_RTL8821A` in the `usb_intf.c` file.

Then I compiled the source code with `make` and `sudo make install` and restarted my PC and the driver doesn't work. It is loaded, because it's showing in `lsmod` everytime I plug my WiFi adapter, but in `lsmod` it's saying `used by: 0`.

I am sure the driver works with the RTL88**21**AU chipset and I am sure Archer T2U Plus is using this chipset, but it doesn't seem to work. I think the problem is that I installed it wrong, or that the `8812au` module showing up in `lsmod` is another module **(that I had tried before trying this package from the universe, because I had tried a lot of different drivers before trying this one)** and the old module is handling the WiFi adapter instead of the `rtl8812au-dkms` package from the universe (compiled from source code with the edited `usb_intf.c` file).

I tried to run `sudo depmod -a` and `sudo modprobe 8812au` before restarting my PC, I also tried to install it while the adapter was unplugged and plugging it after a reboot, I tried using USB 3.0 ports on my case, USB 2.0 and 3.0 on my motherboard, nothing worked.

Can you please guide me step-by-step on how to compile and install the driver after I edited the source code or how to see if the module really is the one with the edited `usb_intf.c` file **(I am new to Linux)**?

BTW the driver has dkms, but because I installed it using `sudo make install` it isn't showing up in the `dkms status`. Also, after installing the driver the WiFi adapter isn't showing up in `nmcli device` or `lshw -C network`, **only in** `lsusb` and the module in `lsmod`.

Comment: Uninstall the driver that you moded, and try https://github.com/morrownr/8821au or https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708

Comment: It doesn't lock partitions. Here is an explanation: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled What does this tell us? sudo modprobe 8812au && sudo dmesg | grep 8812 Please edit your question to show the results. I have deleted my usually accurate but not today answer.